# Page doesn't show full content in Chrome but it loads when I hit ESC to stop loading. Other browsers works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, pageload

I have no clue what is preventing a page to show its contents in Chrome. It only shows the content when I hit ESC after waiting a long time for it to load.

Other browsers works fine.

This is what it's expected to show:
[image: expected]

But it's blank until I press ESC to stop page loading:
[image: actual]

It happens only in Chrome. I can't find anything in the inspector preventing the page to load fully.

Comment: How can we help you if you don't provide us your code?

Comment: More specifically, try to demonstrate the problem with a [short self contained complete example](http://sscce.org) rather than dumping *all* of your code here

Comment: Is this only a problem on your PC or in your building?
I had a similar problem on my pages once and it was not my fault. The browser was attempting to load an image off a yelp server that was down and would take several minutes before timing out. after a few hours it was still broken but only on my PC. I had to flush my dns to get the new yelp server ip.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella Sorry, my mistake. I thought I had posted the URL of the page.

This is the URL: http://www.motonline.com.br/noticia/busca/

Comment: @JAX This problem was reported by one of our clients :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the chrome developer tools to see what your page tries to load over the network or if there are errors in the console.
Maybe this will help you or you could provide at least this as additional information on your question.